# Cypress in docker can't find cypress.json file

Tags: docker, cucumber, cypress, e2e

I'm struggling with testing my app with my Cypress with docker, I use the dedicated docker image with this command  : `docker run -it -v $PWD:/e2e -w /e2e cypress/included:8.7.0`

I have ALWAYS this error when I launch it : `Could not find a Cypress configuration file, exiting.

We looked but did not find a default config file in this folder: /e2e`

Meaning that cypress can't find the cypress.json but it is precisely in the dedicated folder, here is my directory/file tree :

```
pace    
   front
      cypress
      cypress.json
```

So this is a standard file tree for e2e testing, and  despite all of my tricks (not using $PWD but using full directory path, reinstall docker, colima engine etc. nothings works, and if I run npm run cypress locally everything works just fine !

Needless to say that I am in the /pace/front directory when I'm trying these commands

Can you help me please ?

Comment: Have you also tried passing the cypress.json explicitly by using the —config-file flag as described here: https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/command-line#cypress-run-config-file-lt-config-file-gt (assuming you are using cypress run to execute your tests)

Comment: Yep i tests this wih an entry point on this ocker and specify the --config-file option, does not work either :/

Answer (score 0):

The `-v $PWD:/e2e` is a docker instruction to mount a volume (a bind mount). It mounts the current directory to `/e2e` inside the docker container at runtime.

In the [docs](https://www.cypress.io/blog/2019/05/02/run-cypress-with-a-single-docker-command/) it mention a structure where it expects the `cypress.json` file to end up directly under `/e2e`. To get it do be like this you have to do either:

- `-v $PWD/pace/front:/e2e`
- run the command from inside the `pace/front` directory

Since the `CMD` and `ENTRYPOINT` commands in docker run from the `WORKDIR` you could also try running it from where you were but changing the workdir as:
`-w /e2e/pace/front`
I have not seen their dockerfile, but my assumption is that that would work.
My personal choice would be to just run it from `pace/front`